# Pass Fixtures dynamically on Cypress

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

I had a question regarding the fixtures which I wasn't able to find in the docs. Can we pass the a particular JSON fixture in the command line. For example, I have two json files user1.json and user2.json and on runtime I want to pass the fixture I require for the test.

Can I do something like npx cypress run *--fixture name* that dynamically passes the json file.

Comment: What is the fixture file actually doing?

Comment: @mvoase the fixture file contains test data that needs to be passed to tests. for example, endpoints for different environments

Comment: You shouldn’t need to run it in using the CLI. If you want to use different environments you should be setting them as an env object of a Cypress.env.json - and then you can use cypress run —env as the cli command. In regards to anything else fixture related test data for example they should be stored in files under the fixtures directory and called in your code using cy.fixture

Comment: See option 4 here for env https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Setting